# How to add different css to one html tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm using two `iframe` tag in my website. 
I added css for 1 tag

```css
<style>
iframe{
    opacity: 0;
    border: 0px none transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
</style>
```

But both `iframe`s are hidden.

I want to show 1 iframe and hide another one. How can I do that?

Comment: Your css applicable for all iframe, separate out using `class` or `id`. your `opacity:0;` creates problem so both iframe invisible.

Comment: Add an id to the iframe you want the styles to apply for and target the iframe by that id `#myIframe` for example

Answer (score 1):

You can use IDs for this if you have a simple page and don't have too many styles to maintain. Below the style tags are the iframes with ID attributes defined. Those ID attributes are used between the style tags to select the iframe element you want to style by ID.

```html
<style>
  /* Using ID selector #iframeOne */
  #iframeOne {
    opacity: 0;
    border: 0px none transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  }
</style>

<!-- Give ID to iframe you want to style. Here it's iframeOne -->
<iframe id="iframeOne"></iframe>

<iframe id="iframeTwo"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these selectors:

```
iframe:first-child{
 // styling
}

iframe:last-child{
 // styling
}
iframe:nth-child(1){
 // styling
}
```

Comment: how can i use that style?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to give the one you wish to hide an id or a class and then let the css be applied to the id (#your_id) or the class (.your_class). So instead of writing `iframe{....` you would write `#your_id{...`  or  `.your_class{....`

Answer (score 0):

You should add ID or Class in your `<iframe>` tag like below code:

**Add ID:**

```
 <iframe id="iframe-1"></iframe>
 <iframe id="iframe-2"></iframe>
```

or

**Add Class:**

```
<iframe class="iframe-1"></iframe>
<iframe class="iframe-2"></iframe>
```

**Below CSS:**

```
<style>
     #iframe-1,
    .iframe-1 {
          /* Your code here */
    }
     #iframe-2,
    .iframe-2 {
          /* Your code here */
    }
</style>
```